# Identify an unknown letter cube game (not Boggle)

Tags: identify-this-game

We managed to lose the instructions of this game and cannot remember the name.  It seems similar to Boggle - but has groups of similar cubes, each with the type in a different colour, and a die.

[image: unknown letter cube game]

The box closes the cubes tight so there is no shaking like Boggle. I tried google goggles but with no luck. The box contains the following six-sided dice sets:

- 6 White dice: D H A R O and a blank.
- 4 Grey dice: P C I S N and a blank.
- 2 Orange dice: F U E T B and a blank.
- 2 Blue dice: J O E L G and a blank.
- 2 Purple dice: K V I T L and a blank.
- 2 Pink dice: Q W E S G and a blank.
- 2 Yellow dice: V U E T M and a blank.
- 2 Green dice: X T M Y E and a blank.
- 2 Red dice: Z Y A W N and a blank.
- and a plain numbered d6

Comment: What about the other faces of the dice? Are there other letters/numbers, or are they all just variations on the ones shown?

Comment: Could be one of these - https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/word_dice_game

Comment: @goldPseudo - updated post with details

Comment: I have just found the game with the instruction booklet. If you'd like I could make a copy and email it to you .

Comment: @Tracy If you could scan and upload somewhere that'd be pretty amazing; we would like to make sure that the knowledge is shared, not just given to the OP here!

Comment: @Tracy You might consider uploading your scanned instruction booklet to [BoardGameGeek's Cubewords files page](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/27935/cubeword/files). That's the largest board game site, and it's a public place that would benefit anybody who is interested in this game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably cubeword.

Check it here: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/27935/cubeword

Comment: The letter list seems to match: https://boardgamegeek.com/image/185077/cubeword